# Conditional configuration to ASP.NET Core exceptionhandling middleware

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm invoking same ASP.NET Core 3.1 middleware but with different options. For instance my `Startup.Configure()` looks like:

```
var exceptionHandlerOptions = new ExceptionHandlerOptions();
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
  // Error in WebApi controller
  exceptionHandlerOptions.ExceptionHandlingPath = "/api-exception-handler";
  appBuilder.UseMiddleware<exceptionhandlermiddleware>(Options.Create(exceptionHandlerOptions));
});
app.UseWhen(context => !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
  // Error in Mvc controller
  exceptionHandlerOptions.ExceptionHandlingPath = "/mvc-exception-handler";
  appBuilder.UseMiddleware<exceptionhandlermiddleware>(Options.Create(exceptionHandlerOptions));
});
```

However, I can't make it to run properly. The `ExceptionHandlingPath` is always `"/mvc-exception-handler"`.

P.S. I trimmed my example for simplicity here. My real implementation is bit different though e.g. I have an extension method on IAppBuilder to wrap UseWhen of Exceptionhandlermiddleware.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle dynamic error pages in .net MVC Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814674/how-to-handle-dynamic-error-pages-in-net-mvc-core)

Comment: Not directly related but useful though. My problem is to invoke same middleware with different options via UseWhen(predicate) not working for me.